# Central Admin Custom Action menu not appearing?

Tags: custom-actions

I am trying to add a custom Menu item under "Site Collections" in central admin. Following is my elements.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
    Id="CheckAllaboutmoss"
    Location="Micorosoft.SharePoint.Administration.Applications"
    Title="Check Allaboutmoss.com availability"
    Sequence="15"
    RequiredAdmin="Delegated"
    Description="Create a new top-level web site, by host header" 
    GroupId="SiteCollections">
        <UrlAction Url="/_layouts/HelloWorld/Hello.aspx"/>
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I deploy the solution and I dont see the new menu item. What could be the reason? I tried adding a menu item to Site Actions menu and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that Location and GroupID attributes mentioned in SDk are not correct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx

The values you specified are correct.

I was able to display a link with following XML, which is pretty similar to yours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction  GroupId="SiteCollections" Id="CheckAllaboutmoss" Sequence="100" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Applications" Title="Check Availability" RequiredAdmin="Delegated" >
    <UrlAction Url="/_admin/createsite.aspx"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

**Please make sure following:
1. You can use Scope = Web or higher (Web makes sense)
2. Make sure you have AutoActivateInCentralAdmin="TRUE" in the FEATURE element of the feature.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still I don't see it. I used the values given here : http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/arjen/archive/2010/02/04/custom-action-definitions-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I think you should be fine with my updated answer..Please review my answer again

Answer (score 1):

Your location is not good.
You wrote Location="**Micorosoft**.SharePoint.Administration.Applications"

instead of

Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Applications"

Answer (score 0):

In the associated feature.xml file, make sure to reference the elements file as follows:

```
<ElementManifest Location="elements.xml" />
```

Once without thinking, I used the "ElementFile" tag instead and for the life of me I couldn't figure out why the custom action wasn't showing up.  I'm not going to own up to how much time I spent trying to resolve the issue.