# How to add a custom link to Central Admin quick launch?

Tags: custom-actions, central-administration

I'm attempting add a page for my collection of apps to the Central Admin quick launch in SharePoint 2010:

[alt text http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/2808/customappcentraladmin.png](http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/2808/customappcentraladmin.png)

Following SharePoint's out-of-the-box behaviour, a custom action group like this should be what's needed:

```
<CustomActionGroup
    Id="MyCentralAdmin"
    Title="My App"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Default"
    Sequence="201"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/myapp/Admin_48x48.png">
    <UrlAction Url="/_admin/myapp/centraladmin.aspx"/>
</CustomActionGroup>
```

This **does** show on the main Central Admin home page. However **not** in the quick launch.

I've noticed that Nintex Workflow can get their page in and I think this XML should be all that's needed. But it doesn't work!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from RequiredAdmin="Delegated" in the CustomActionGroup, please make sure following:

1. You can use Scope = Web or higher (Web makes sense)
2. Make sure you have AutoActivateInCentralAdmin="TRUE" in the FEATURE element of the feature

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding RequiredAdmin="Delegated" to your CustomActionGroup?

Have a look at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6689/central-admin-custom-action-menu-not-appearing) as well

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. RequiredAdmin isn't even documented - I'm not sure what that does.

Comment: Description lies here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx